# Invariant amplitude in QED in terms of Mandelstam variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, kinematics, momentum, quantum-electrodynamics

So I'm having a little trouble with this question:

[image]

These are my workings thus far:

[image]

I just can't seem to get certain terms to vanish. I have the 1/4 factor for going between $8e^4$ to $2e^4$. Is there some hint when it says in the relativistic regime?

I hope my workings are clear too. If anyone can push me over the finishing line Id be very grateful. Many thanks.

Comment: In the relativistic regime, you may ignore the mass terms so that $s+t+u=0$.

Comment: So $P_{i}^{2}$ becomes $m_{i}^{2}$ and I can neglect mass?

Comment: Yes exactly - for example, $P_i \cdot P_j $ are expressible entirely in terms of the mandelstam variables so that e.g $P_1 \cdot P_2 = s/2$ for example.